# json_encode treats a single element array as object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, encoding

this is the json i have to produce

```
{
  "email": "example@example.com",
  "campaign": {
    "campaignId": "p86zQ"
  },
  "customFieldValues": [
    {
      "customFieldId": "y8jnp",
      "value": ["18-29"]
    }
  ]
}
```

if i use

```
$data = [
        "email" => $_POST['mail'],
        "campaign" => [
            "campaignId" => "4JIXJ"
        ],
        "customFieldValues" => [
            "customFieldId" => "y8jnp",
            "value" => ["18-29"]
        ]
    ];
```

and i do json_encode($data)

value is an object, but it should be an array with a single element. Somehow json_encode treats it as an object. Can i force it to treat it as an array with a single element ?

Thanks in Advance

Adrian

Comment: @treyBake  it needs to be `json_decode()` not `json_encode()`

Comment: adding true didnt work  :(

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie heh, my bad

Comment: @AdrianGier did you try with `json_decode($data, true)`? Was my bad - just used `_encode` by mistake

Comment: As demonstrated by aynber's and the dupe target, you only need to nest the `customFieldValues` data one level deeper by wrapping the data in `[` and `]` -- this will change the object to be an array containing an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, you have a single array with 2 elements, instead of an array with a single element of a sub-array. In order to get the json in the first section, you need to add another array level.

```
$data = [
        "email" => $_POST['mail'],
        "campaign" => [
            "campaignId" => "4JIXJ"
        ],
        "customFieldValues" => [
            [
                "customFieldId" => "y8jnp",
                "value" => ["18-29"]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

That will give you this:

```
{
    "email": null,
    "campaign": {
        "campaignId": "4JIXJ"
    },
    "customFieldValues": [
       {
          "customFieldId": "y8jnp",
          "value": ["18-29"]
       }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if there is one single element in the array the json_encode will treat is as an object and the key of the object is the index of the array
to treat it as an array you can use **array_values(<your_array>)**